# How to program Linux Kernel Header files using make?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, clang

I am programming on Ubuntu20.04, have installed linux kernel headers, and generally understand path, and tools for finding files such as `find`.

My kernel version is

```
$ uname -r 
5.15.0-69-generic

$ ls /usr/src | grep linux-headers-$(uname -r)
linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic
```

So the header files are installed.

Let's say I want to compile this simple program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/skbuff.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

If I simply build with `gcc`, I get

```
gcc -o temp.o temp.c
temp.c:2:10: fatal error: linux/skbuff.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <linux/skbuff.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

In VSCODE code editor, there are path errors as well, intellisense cannot these files in the default directories listed by

```
gcc temp.c -v
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

I have simply imported the skbuff header. I have configured my vscode `c_cpp_properties.json" as such

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/generated",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/",
                "/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/uapi"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

This is fine. There are no path errors now and I can smoothly transition and look through the source files in vscode.

Now I want to compile it. Lets say my C file is `temp.c`, here is my Makefile

```
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDFLAGS=

# Path to the Linux kernel source directory
KERNEL_SRC = /usr/src/linux-headers-$(shell uname -r)

# Include directories for kernel headers
INCLUDE_DIRS = \
    -I$(KERNEL_SRC)/arch/x86/include/ \
    -I$(KERNEL_SRC)/arch/x86/include/generated/ \
    -I$(KERNEL_SRC)/include/ \
    -I$(KERNEL_SRC)/include/uapi/


# Object files
OBJS = temp.o

# Targets
all: temp

temp: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    @echo $(INCLUDE_DIRS)
    rm -f *.o temp
```

However, this just breaks. When running `make all`, there are endless errors. For example

```
In file included from temp.c:2:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h:15:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/time.h:60:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/time32.h:13:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/timex.h:67:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:13:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:59:8: error: redefinition of 'pt_regs'
struct pt_regs {
       ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/ptrace.h:44:8: note: previous definition is here
struct pt_regs {
       ^
In file included from temp.c:2:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/skbuff.h:15:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/time.h:60:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/time32.h:13:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/timex.h:67:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:5:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:13:
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:114:15: error: no member named 'ax' in 'struct pt_regs'
```

Is this a compiler issue, path issue, or both?

Some other maybe relevant things

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep gcc
c89-gcc
c99-gcc
gcc
gcc-9
gcc-ar
gcc-ar-9
gcc-nm
gcc-nm-9
gcc-ranlib
gcc-ranlib-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9

$ clang --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep clang
clang
clang++
clang++-10
clang-10
clang-cpp-10
```

Any insight into creating an environment (template Makefile, vscode settings) for this type of development would be helpful! Thanks.

### Edit

Some other attempts

Just using include <skbuff.h>, I get

```
$ gcc -I/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux -o temp.o temp.c 

In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33, from temp.c:1: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/stddef.h:5:10: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory     
5 | #include <uapi/linux/stddef.h>       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

A header file within skbuff is now broken.

Without -I

```
gcc -o temp.o temp.c temp.c:2:10: fatal error: linux/skbuff.h: No such file or directory     
2 | #include <linux/skbuff.h>       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Assuming that you have control over the line in question (`#include <linux/skbuff.h>`), I recommend to first try to get it working without make and without the path in the include. I.e. make sure your search paths do the job, using `#include <skbuff.h>`.

Comment: Let me know whether my assumption is applicable. I am aware that sometimes there is need to build with that kind of includes given and unchangeable and in that case my proposal of course does not help you.

Comment: @Yunnosch with just `include <skbuff.h>`, I get ```gcc -I /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux -o temp.o temp.c
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:33,
                 from temp.c:1:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-69-generic/include/linux/stddef.h:5:10: fatal error: uapi/linux/stddef.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <uapi/linux/stddef.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```. A header file within skbuff is now broken.

Comment: WIthout -I path set, ```gcc -o temp.o temp.c
temp.c:2:10: fatal error: linux/skbuff.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <linux/skbuff.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.```

Comment: You probably want to [edit] in order to provide that helpful information with helpful formatting to the question. I think it means that the search paths won't help you... Sorry. But that is info other potential answerers might need or probably at least appreciate.

Comment: Why do you want to include <linux/skbuff.h>? That is part of the kernel's internal API, not part of the kernel's userspace API, and you do not seem to be trying to build an external kernel module. It also includes lots of other header files that are part of the kernel's internal API.

Comment: @IanAbbott I want to program eBPF functions, which rely on these headers. Path errors pop up all the time when setting up my development environment, and I want to know the best way to create such an environment, and thus be able to compile my own (possible eBPF programs) programs that can be inserted into the linux kernel.

Comment: stdio.h is not a kernel header.  When you compile code to run _inside_ the kernel, you don't have access to userspace facilities like stdio and you can't just print content like that.  If you compile for userspace, then you don't have access to internal kernel facilities like skbuff.  So, you can't build the code you are trying to build.  You need to decide whether your program will run in userspace, or in kernel space, and use only the facilities available in the one you choose.

Comment: This is more a question on *using or configuring* programming tools, rather than on programming itself. Maybe https://superuser.com/ would be the place to ask.